# PHPUnit Selenium2TestCase running all methods in class

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I've recently updated my testing dependancies through composer from:

```
   "phpunit/phpunit": "8.5.*
   "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "8.0.0",
```

To the following versions: (running on php 7.4)

```
   "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "^9.0",
   "se/selenium-server-standalone": "3.141.59",
   "phpunit/phpunit": "9.5.*",
```

Though after going through the update I've seem to come across an error where every member method of the class is trying to be executed on every invocation of this test suite. My php xml file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="false"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         processIsolation="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="feature">
            <file>tests/feature/WordpressTest.php</file>
            <file>tests/feature/RestTest.php</file>
            <file>tests/feature/BracketTest.php</file>
            <file>tests/feature/PayPalTest.php</file>
            <file>tests/feature/TwitchApiTest.php</file>
            <file>tests/feature/DiscordApiTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="browser">
            <file>tests/browser/NavigationTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <env name="TEST" value="TRUE"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <ini name="display_errors" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I don't have this issue with the feature tests, but only the browser which extend Selenium2TestCase. You can see in the media attached that the common function setUp is trying to be run like a test and `startSeleniumServer()` which is not prefixed with test either. Even if only one member method is given, phpunit will try to run all members of `Selenium2TestCase`. I think I maybe missing a new annotation or may need to redefine a filter... I'm confused why this behavior would also be observed by intelliJ (my editor) when trying to execute a single test from cgi. Inevitably all tests will run. It should be noted that the test I need to run is actually passing too. So the issues is strictly the methods not prefixed with test running.

[image: Visual reference of incorrect methods being run]

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Sorry to say it's still happening to me. I've neglected my testing; I'll give it another shot sometime this week and let you know.

Comment: @CatalinaDeLaCuesta What versions are you running?